# Add Columns to a SQL Row from Count of Unique Values in One Column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have two columns I am interested in:

```
bought_time           |    product
-----------------------------------
1990-10-26T09:00:00Z  | bicycle
1990-10-26T09:00:01Z  | car
1990-10-26T09:13:22Z  | bicycle
1990-10-26T09:26:11Z  | cookies
1990-10-26T09:26:13Z  | milk
1990-10-26T09:27:16Z  | milk
```

I want to create a SQLite query in Ruby on Rails that will return this after being converted by as_json:

```
[{date by minute: 1990-10-26T09:00:00Z, bicycle: 1, car: 1, cookies:0, milk:0}, {date by minute: 1990-10-26T09:13:00Z, bicycle:1, car:0, cookies:0, milk:0}, {date by minute: 1990-10-26T09:26:00Z, bicycle:0, car:0, cookies:1, milk:1}, {date by minute: 1990-10-26T09:26:00Z, bicycle:0, car:0, cookies:0, milk:1} ]
```

So far I have something like:

```
Bought.select("datetime((strftime('%s', date)/60)*60, 'unixepoch') interval, count(type)").where("date(date) >= date(:from) AND date(date) <= date(:to)", {from: event_params["from"], to: event_params["to"]}).order("interval").group("type").group("interval")
```

Which in SQL is

```
SELECT datetime((strftime('%s', date)/60)*60, 'unixepoch') interval, count(type), type FROM "events" WHERE (date(date) >= date('1985-10-26T09:00:00Z') AND date(date) <= date('1985-10-27T09:00:00Z')) GROUP BY interval, "events"."type"  ORDER BY interval
```

but I am at a loss at how to proceed from here.

Comment: Are you only using sqlite? If you're doing a custom query like this, especially one that groups on a date, you should use the database you'll be  using in production for the sake of compatibility. Otherwise, you'll find some queries work in sqlite that don't work in your production db and vice-versa.

Comment: Currently there are no plans yet to move this to production---but either way the Ruby syntax should work even when I shift servers, no?